# How to make progressive operations in data frames with dplyr or similar R packages?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 b = c(6,5,4,6,1))
```

I need to create a 'c' column that sums the i-th element from 'a' to the (i+1)-th element of 'b' and stores it in the i-th position of 'c', and the last element of 'c' would be equal to the value of its corresponding 'a' value.
Inside a for loop, the code would be something like this:

```
#Initialize the 'c' column
df$c <- vector("double", nrow(df))

#For Loop
for(i in (1:(nrow(df)-1)){
 df$c[i] <- df$a[i] + df$b[i+1]
}
df$c[nrow(df)] <- df$a[nrow(df)]
```

I am familiarized with dplyr::mutate(), but I don't know how to replace that loop with this function. Is there any other function from dplyr or another package than can help me with this kind of operations?

Comment: `transform(df,c=a+c(b[-1],0))` or `df$c <- df$a+c(df$b[-1],0)` or `transform(df,c=a+c(tail(b,-1),0))` etc etc

Answer (score 2):

Using `lead()` in `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    mutate(c = a + lead(b, default = 0))
```

Comment: or just `df %>% mutate(c = a + lead(b, default = 0))` to deal with the last row

Comment: Yes that's much better, I was going to check if `lead()` had an argument like that but must have forgotten.

Comment: Thanks Marius! I didn't know it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table::shift` to lead the b column to be summed with a:

```
dt[, C := ifelse(is.na(shift(b, type="lead")), a, a + shift(b, type="lead"))][]
```

Or using `replace` to handle the tail case:

```
dt[, C := {
        x <- shift(b, type="lead")
        a + replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
    }]
```

missed out the `fill` argument in `shift` (i.e. equivalent of `default` in `dplyr::lead`)

```
df[, C := a + shift(b, fill=0, type="lead")]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 b = c(6,5,4,6,1))
```